# P_values and effect size

Tags: p-value, effect-size, statistical-power

I have a question about the effect size,p_values, and power? first, what are their differences? And also do I need to report the value of all of them and not just p values?

Comment: The basic differences between these terms are best explained in formal statistics manuals and guides such as Andy Fields Introduction to statistics through <insert favourite statistical programming language>, or (even) through wikipedia (see for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value). Whether or not you should report these values depends on your research question, method of (statistical) analysis and you statistical 'upbringing'. In short, this is a very broad question, which you might want to specify.

Comment: @ IWS, thanks for the comment, for example, if I use ANOVA, do I need to report the P values and also effect size or just p-value would be enough?

Comment: Following APA guidelines, you should never report a p-value by itself but always with its test statistic and degrees of freedom. That said, the p-value should not be the focus of your interpretation but simply a guide to interpretation. The focus should be on the effect size or more generally, on your actual results. That is, what effect did you find? How big was it? What was the direction of the effect? Studies that only report p-values contribute little to the scientific literature.

Comment: By the way, both the APA and the ASA recommend reporting effect sizes and confidence intervals rather than focuses on p-values.

Comment: I'm really hesitant to try to answer your question mehrbanoo. A lot more context is needed. IMO @dbwilson 's suggestion to look at the APA and/or ASA guidelines is very good and might provide insight in the difficulty of the matter. Most importantly do not generalize too quickly!

Comment: I agree with IWS. You're asking very broad questions about the definitions of some quite elemental concepts in statistics. If you really have no idea what these things mean, I think you'd be better off reading a textbook or taking a basic statistics course. CV is better suited for specific questions. If you've studied these topics already and are struggling with certain details, I would recommend explaining in your question what it is exactly that you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 5):

I will explain everything based on a example.

- a coin is flipped 100 times. Call $X$ the number of heads.
- $\theta$ is the true and unknown probability of "heads".
- Null hypothesis : the coin is unbiased ($\theta=0.5$).
- Our test is based on the distance from 50 to X : $d=|X-50|$. It is called the [statistical summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summary_statistics). For example, if you get $X=33$ heads, $d=17$.

[p-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) is the probability, assuming the coin is unbiased, that you see what you see : $P(d\geq 17|\theta=0.5)$. A small p-value means "if the coin was biased, what I see would be very unlikely".

You decide to set an arbitrary limit for the p-value, say $\alpha=0.05$. Then your test is fully defined:

- if p-value $>\alpha$, answer : accept unbiased
- if p-value $<\alpha$, answer : reject unbiased

$\alpha$ is then the probability of a **false positive**.

Now you can define the power.

[Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power) is the probability, assuming the coin is biased, that you reject unbiased. It is the probability of a **true positive**.  But it depends a lot on how much the coin is biased. Suppose the coin is biased with $\theta=0.500001$ then obviously your test won't help much finding this bias. Thus the power depends on the intensity of the bias. Power is mathematically $P(\text{reject}|\theta)$. It is a function of $\theta$. It looks like a bell curve. Here it is :

[image]

The power depends a lot on the amount of information available in the data. If you flip it 1000 times instead of 100, then the power looks like :

[image]

That's why we sometimes say "the statistical power of the data". The power also depends on the mathematical intelligence of the test. For the same data, a better test can have better power.

The true (and unknown) [effect size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size) here is somehow $|\theta-0.5|$. It is how much the null hypothesis is false. The better data (better power), the more you can detect the effect (reject null) for a small effect size.

So $\alpha$, power and effect size are different notions but mathematically interdependent:

- take greater $\alpha$, you have a more power. But it makes the test more dangerous. It's only trading safety for success.
- if the effect size is stronger, the power is stronger (see the curves).
- otherwise, if you want more power, you need more (better) data (or sometimes a better test)

Comment: thanks for the comment. I have a question. We need to calculate the sample size before collecting the data. In order to estimate the sample size, we need to set the value of power, alpha prior to the implementation of a research study. And most of the time we consider alpha 0.05 and power=0.8. It means the model will have the high power and a good number of samples. So why we need again report the value of effect size? Also if I run the regression, each variable has specific effect size or we have just one effect size for the whole model.

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to report P values and effect sizes. Both are forms of evidence to support your hypothesis. The p value is not the end all or be all of statistical evidence, nor is the effect size.

They work in tandem, along with fit indices, to provide evidence. The more evidence you provide, the better.

Answer (score 0):

Effect size: indicates the quality of your model. e.g. in an ANOVA it is the variance in the dependent variable that is explained by the independent variable

P-value: significant/probability that data differ

Power: Is needed if your test is not significant. If your test has enough power, you can conclude from a not significant e.g. ANOVA that your H0 is correct. So, like p value it’s a probability.

In most cases, it doesn't make sense to report effect size and power. But this is up to the context.

Please specify your question if you need more detailed explanation.

Comment: I don't understand the down vote. Why?

Answer (score 0):

In short: Let's suppose you are studying influence of a factor on a response using ANOVA. Effect size is your estimate of how much a treatment affects the response. P-value tells you about how sure you can be that effect size is actually different than zero.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

The question conveys that some basic explanation of the concepts involved is in order, but first, the short answer: Look at relevant journal articles you use in your paper and see how they do it. *Do the same*.

The long answer: As others have said - report effect size of coefficients and p-values, at a bare minimum. Also - concocting a table with models, sizes, p-values (often as a symbolic $*$ to denominate significant results) and standard errors is common. See a related journal for examples.

Effect size is the influence of $x$ of $y$. Report these if the effect is focal. Saying that the acidity of a solution affects the mortality of cells means much less than saying that an increase in 1% of the acidity of the solution tends to increase mortality by 5%. This is not always the case. Sometimes , especially with control variables, the effect size does not matter, only that there is or is not an effect. ...controling for company size, which has a small but insignificant effect on wages, the gender of the applicant... Effect size is important especially when the effect is important.

Significance (*p-value*) is whether the effect size was large enough, on your sample size, so that it is possible to say, with a certain certainty ($0.05$, $0.01$ etc..) that the effect is different from zero. Put another way, this is the chance of error if we conclude that the sample was taken from a population in which the there is an effect between $x$ and $y$ (controlling for other variables in the model). This is, in a way, the question of is there an effect worth talking about, or not. While the significance is definitely affected by the effect size, large effects can be insignificant and small ones can be significant, depending on standard error. Significance is *always* (within a 0.05 chance of error) reported.

The power is the probability of the model to show significance, when significance is due. That is, to show a significant effect when indeed there is a significant effect in the population. In my discipline (Sociology/Management) this is not a common thing to report.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I have a question. We need to calculate the sample size before collecting the data. In order to estimate the sample size, we need to set the value of power, alpha prior to the implementation of a research study. And most of the time we consider alpha 0.05 and power=0.8. It means the model will have the high power and a good number of samples. So why we need again report the value of effect size? Also if I run the regression, each variable has specific effect size or we have just one effect size for the whole model.

Answer (score 0):

As asked, `P value, power and effect size` are key parameters to evaluate result of hypothesis testing. Following can be a useful algorithm. `Cohen's d` is used as effect size here but it can be replaced with other appropriate effect size depending on test used:

[image]

In above algorithm, results are categorized into 8 categories rather than just `significant` or `non-significant` based on P-value alone.